# Unable to include login check in custom app inside WordPress directory

Tags: php, wordpress

I created simple app that fetches product stock and displays it inside table. I need to secure the access to it so only logged in users can see the data. My app resides in subdirectory in wordpress "root/app/index.php".

I tried using code below but it always end the same: Even after being logged in, the page doesn't see it and always displays the login  form.

```
<?php
session_start();
// Include WordPress functions
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-login.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php');

// Check if the user is logged in
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    // User is logged in, allow access to your app
    echo "Welcome to my app!";
} else {
    wp_redirect(wp_login_url());
    exit;
}
?>
```

Changing the require_once, I also tried this version:

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

if ($current_user->ID == '') {
```